# More efficient method for storing records from a file

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

Recently in discussion I was asked:
You have **one** flat file containing many records say 5 million.
You need to write a Java program that can fetch records from this file and store it in database say via JDBC.
What will be the most efficient approach?

My suggestion was to create:

- one thread that will handle JDBC connection (additionally can make the connection class singleton)
- another thread that will fetch records from file & save in table.
- additionally when a certain number of records are saved in database, say 100 then commit those first then continue.

Here Stored procedures would be better or is there any other way?

Comment: If you are just loading the file the file, Oracle has batch file loader which be more efficient. Alternatively you could load into a Temp Table and use SQL to transform the file

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have the right approach in mind.

The cost and time spent on network I/O and DB operations is going to be much larger than a the file IO and parsing time spent on the flat file.  There might be some small performance gain in having a separate thread read the file and prepare a record for the DB, but it probably wouldn't be worth the added complexity, and maybe not worth the time the JVM would spend on thread management.   I'd recommend:

- 1 thread to read the file and submit DB updates.
- As bitfiddler says, use PreparedStatements with batch updates (`preparedStatement.addBatch()`) for every record, and submit the batch (`preparedStatement.executeBatch()`) every "N" records.  You may want to prototype to see what the ideal value of "N" is, but 100 is a good place to start.

I don't recommend stored procedures.  They won't do much for you if you're just doing straight inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Using prepared statements is important here as it will cut down on the overhead involved for each insert. You certainly don't want it to parse "insert into blah.." every time. I wouldn't worry about managing threads for reading the file and so on, that's what the OS does for you anyway. Just read big chunks of the file through a buffer and do inserts from that. You might think about dividing the file into chunks by spawning several instances of inserter tasks that start by seeking into the file and read chunks from there. The OS should buffer reads so the seeking won't be bad. Of course if your DB isn't on a RAID or at least another volume, all bets are off. Just some thoughts to stir the pot...

Comment: I wouldn't say that whatever "overhead" is limited to query parsing.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - agreed, the parsing certainly is only part of it.